# Mongoose Populate Multiple Fields

Tags: javascript, mongodb, api, mongoose

I am trying to use Mongoose like a relational db.  I have a task schema that needs to reference client, user and note schemas.

I have found many examples for populating one schema with another, but none for when I need to populate more than one.  I have tried the following links:
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html
http://ronaldroe.com/populating-multiple-fields-and-levels-with-mongoose/

```
findAll: function (req, res) {
    Task
      .find(req.query)
      .sort({ date: -1 })
      // populate associated user
      .populate("user", "_id firstName lastName")
      // populate associated client
      .populate("client", "_id name")
      // all notes for the task and when they were created
      .populate("note", "_id content created_at")
      .then(dbModel => {
        res.status(200).json({
          tasks: dbModel.map(model => {
            return {
              _id: model._id,
              user: model.user,
              client: model.client,
              assignDate: model.assignDate,
              assignedStatus: model.assignedStatus,
              completionStatus: model.completionStatus,
              description: model.description,
              note: model.note,
            };
          })
        })
      })
      .catch(err => res.status(422).json(err));
  }
```

When I do a GET request for this data, I get the following:

```
"tasks": [
        {
            "_id": "5d6980d8459a8b9f0e133d04",
            "user": [
                {
                    "_id": "5d6afd8a101f355244adfd9a",
                    "firstName": "Dexter",
                    "lastName": "Morgan"
                }
            ],
            "assignDate": "2018-12-09T00:00:00.000Z",
            "assignedStatus": "true",
            "completionStatus": "in-progress",
            "description": "This client needs to be contacted for future sales"
        }
]
```

I want to also get the client id and name as well as all notes associated with this task.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
findAll: function (req, res) {
    Task
      .find(req.query)
      .sort({ date: -1 })
      // populate associated user
      .populate({path : 'user' , select: '_id firstName lastName'}) 
      // populate associated client
      .populate({path : 'client' , select: '_id name'})
      // all notes for the task and when they were created
      .populate({path : 'note' , select : '_id content created_at'})
      .then(dbModel => {
        res.status(200).json({
          tasks: dbModel.map(model => {
            return {
              _id: model._id,
              user: model.user,
              client: model.client,
              assignDate: model.assignDate,
              assignedStatus: model.assignedStatus,
              completionStatus: model.completionStatus,
              description: model.description,
              note: model.note,
            };
          })
        })
      })
      .catch(err => res.status(422).json(err));
  }
```